# How to pass the email id that to be synchronized into create event calendar in android?

Tags: java, android, calendar

In android we insert an event programmatically through intent. we insert title,  description and time . But there is no key found to insert attendee mail id and recipient mail id into a calendar event. If it is impossible, Why is this not possible & If Possible , How do i achieve it?

Brief Explanation of question:
How to pass the mail id of the calendar that to be synchronized into the create event through email?
I have a spinner that shows the list of accounts to be synchronized . Now, as usual passing title,description to create event in calendar application, i use following code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", title1);
    values.put("allDay", 0);
    values.put("dtstart", settime); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
    values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
    values.put("description", desc1);
    values.put("???????", mail_id);
    values.put("???????", participant_mail_id);
    values.put("visibility", 0);
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

What should i use to pass the key to insert email id and participant id? Any Help is really appreciated. My screen shot goes below.

Comment: android calendar api is not a public API. I used this method to add events to calendar but it does not seem to work properly with HTC devices.The end date and time does are not correct. I tried to add location also but could not. Anyways looking forward to some cool answers to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar Provider is public since ICS (API Level - 14). More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

To add attendees you need the event id, so you need to add event first.

Example for API level >=14:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// add event
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

// add attendee
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "Trevor");
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, "trevor@example.com");
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE);
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, Attendees.TYPE_OPTIONAL);
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
values.put(Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
cr.insert(Attendees.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Example for API level < 14:

```
String calendarLocation;
// set calendar URI (depends on api level)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
    calendarLocation = "content://com.android.calendar/"; 
} else {
    calendarLocation = "content://calendar/";
}

// URIs for events and attendees tables
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(calendarLocation + "events");
Uri ATTENDEES_URI = Uri.parse(calendarLocation + "attendees");

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// add event
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("dtstart", startMillis);
values.put("dtend", endMillis);
values.put("title", "Jazzercise");
values.put("description", "Group workout");
values.put("calendar_id", calID);
values.put("eventTimezone", "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

// add attendee
values = new ContentValues();
values.put("attendeeName", "Trevor");
values.put("attendeeEmail", "trevor@example.com");
values.put("attendeeRelationship", 1);
values.put("attendeeType", 2);
values.put("attendeeStatus", 3);
values.put("event_id", eventID);
cr.insert(ATTENDEES_URI, values);
```